# BlackBerry PlayBook Webworks: Low frame rate

Tags: javascript, blackberry, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook

While my blackberry webworks app works very well on Blackberry 7.0 and 7.1 devices, it has a very low frame rate on PlayBooks. For example when scrolling on a page or when drawing stuff on a canvas. I use the jQuery JavaScript extension.

What could be the reason for the low frame rate that makes it rather unusable on PlayBook devices?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using jQuery Mobile over jQuery-UI as it is more optimized for mobile.  jQuery in general generates a lot of page repaints, which is expensive for smooth UI.  Do you have many pages in your app?

Finally, if you are using a JavaScript library like iScroll to introduce kinetic scrolling, I'd recommend disabling that - the native web engine does this for you.